# What element should I use for fixed sidebar with links to other parts of the page?

Tags: html, css, sidebar, semantics

On [StackOverflow home page](https://stackoverflow.com/), the sidebar (the one with the links to home itself, tags, users, and so on) is a `div`, but I'm wondering whether another HTML element is more semantically correct.

I see that probably the answer depends on what the sidebar is for. In the use I imagine on [my embrio-blog](https://aster89.github.io/#posts), the side bar would have a link to all entries across the 4 tabs.

Answer (score 0):

If the sidebar is going to be a list of links, then you can use the `nav` tag. On the Stack Overflow site the outermost container is a `div` for styling but it is using a `nav` tag within for the links and tags.

[MDN Docs on the Nav tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)